# Emacs: Runnning R shell

Tags: r, emacs

I am running R REPL, inside Emacs. It is displaying Unicode character as follows:

```
> summary(one.way)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Group       15  49695    3313   3.556 0.000366 ***
Residuals   50  46589     932                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 â€˜***â€™ 0.001 â€˜**â€™ 0.01 â€˜*â€™ 0.05 â€˜.â€™ 0.1 â€˜ â€™ 1
```

How to enable Unicode characters in Emacs?

**UPDATE**
I am using Ubuntu 18.4 and I guess, it is GUI Emacs (XEmacs, but not sure).

Comment: Can you provide more information? What OS are you running? Do you know which locale you’re using? Is the `one.way` object an ANOVA generated by `aov`?

Comment: I don't know how to find the locale.  The `one.way` object is generated by `aov`. I am using Ubuntu and please see the update.  This happens when I copy something from web into Emacs. It asks for the encoding when I save. Particularly back-quote and front-quote (single). Here also, the problem is with these.

Comment: You can run `Sys.getlocale()` at the R command line; the problematic characters are supposed to be curly single quotes `‘` and `’`

Comment: I get the output `> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_IN;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_IN;LC_COLLATE=en_IN;LC_MONETARY=en_IN;LC_MESSAGES=en_IN;LC_PAPER=en_IN;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"`.  What to do with this? OR how to set it?

Comment: Yeah, that shows that you're not using a UTF-8 locale otherwise you'd have `LC_CTYPE=en_IN.UTF-8` in the output, so that explains why you get the extra symbols in the summary. Here's Ubuntu's documentation on changing locales: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale